# Reading a single number from another file using python

Tags: python, parsing, numbers

I am reading a number from a file p2.txt. This file contrains only 1 number which is an integer lets say 10.

```
test_file = open('p2.txt', 'r') 
test_lines = test_file.readlines() 
test_file.close() 
ferNum= test_lines[0] 
print int(ferNum)
```

when however, I am getting an error

```
print int(ferNum)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.100000000000000000e+01\n'
```

I can see that it is considering it just as a line. How can I parse that number to a variable?  any suggestions? regards

Comment: You should include the input, otherwise you'll receive wild guesses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that even though the *value* of the number is an integer (11) it is represented in scientific notation so you'd have to read it as a `float` first.

```
>>> float('1.100000000000000000e+01\n')
11.0

>>> int('1.100000000000000000e+01\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    int('1.100000000000000000e+01\n')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.100000000000000000e+01\n'
```

You can of course convert first to a `float` then to an `int` after that.

```
>>> int(float('1.100000000000000000e+01\n'))
11
```